# Multiple invocations of same method on a mock with minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mocking, minitest

I am using the version of minitest with Ruby 1.9.3
How do I test for multiple invocations of a mock with it? I need something like

```
mockObject.expect.times(2) :method, [return_1 first time, return_2 second time] 
mockObject.verify
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately my minitest version is older. This has only been supported since this commit. https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/commit/7a6f1818877c6c8a83a0e6680d5fc23ec32fa633#diff-00a18d559ad9a1e984068e38e5009047

Comment: Unfortunately you're using Minitest :(

Comment: This library needs to be removed from the net. I have lost almost two days working around multiple issues trying to test very basic stuff.

Answer (score 10):

You need to call [`expect`](http://docs.seattlerb.org/minitest/Minitest/Mock.html#method-i-expect) for each time the method is to be called.

```
mockObject.expect :method, return_1, [first, time, args]
mockObject.expect :method, return_2, [second, time, args]

# run your code using the mock object

mockObject.verify
```

Comment: this does not work actually. I get a `MockExpectationError` which says `expected{:retval => return_2, :args => [second, time, args]}, got [{:retval => return_1, :args => [first, time, args]}, {:retval => return_2, :args => [second, time, args]}]` From what I understand, if I'm mocking the same method multiple times, the last 'expect' is winning and the rest are ignored. Maybe something wrong with the minitest version in Ruby 1.9.3?